# PIL open tif image only one channel

Tags: python, numpy, tiff, python-imaging-library

There are two situations when I open tif image by PIL. First one is a normal one that can open an image as RGB and display by plt well. However, the second one as shown in the codes below:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = Image.open('test1.tif')
a = np.array(img)
a.shape
# output: (2040,2040)
```

can only open as a shape of (2040,2040), the previous one with a shape of (2040,2040,3). When I convert the (2040,2040) one into RGB mode using `img = img.convert('RGB')` and showing it via plt only saw a blank square.

Please, somebody, tell me what is going wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Original Image:
[image]

And numpy array:

```
array([[7256, 6926, 7270, ..., 7368, 7457, 7555],
   [7174, 6945, 6878, ..., 7401, 7353, 7895],
   [7288, 7099, 7140, ..., 7359, 7524, 7587],
   ...,
   [6769, 6695, 6698, ..., 6599, 6788, 6898],
   [6780, 6683, 6857, ..., 6723, 6761, 6861],
   [6788, 6626, 6761, ..., 6738, 6751, 7054]], dtype=uint16)
```

After convert to RGB mode:
[image]
numpy array:

```
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: can you print the value of a[0][0] or some other sample of the values of a?

Comment: @Zev Yes, I can print them all. before converting to RGB mode, the value is 1000+, and after all values are 255

Comment: Can you share the image?

Comment: @Zev I updated the questions by adding the images

Comment: You don't mention which specific matplotlib function you use. Have you tried `plt.imshow()`?

Comment: @OliverEvans Yes, but won't work.

Comment: @Zev Your answer enlighten me. Why can't I just convert the image to png first? (Sorry for my IQ.) and I used the codes 
    
    ``image = Image.open("test1.tif"),
      image.mode = 'I' ,
      image = image.point(lambda i:i*(1./256)).convert('L'),
      image = image.convert('RGB')``

and it works! (Sorry I don't know how to edit the codes in comments)

Comment: @Zev But could you tell me why this happen? Some images only have one channel?

Comment: See my answer, it is because it is a 16-bit image and PIL is for 8-bit images. Black and white images just have one channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are having is because the image is a 16-bit image (uint16) which is unsupported by the PIL image library. You can, as you suggested, simply convert it to a different image type. However, you can also just use `imageio`

The following code should work:

```
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img = imageio.imread('test1.tif')
plt.imshow(img)
```

See here for a discussion of related topics: https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/204

BTW, here's a list of PIL image formats and how many channels they have (Adapted from https://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Python_usage_notes_-_PIL):

```
PIL pixel formats:

RGB 24bits per pixel, 8-bit-per-channel RGB), 3 channels
RGBA (8-bit-per-channel RGBA), 4 channels
RGBa (8-bit-per-channel RGBA, remultiplied alpha), 4 channels
1 - 1bpp, often for masks, 1 channel
L - 8bpp, grayscale, 1 channel
P - 8bpp, paletted, 1 channel
I - 32-bit integers, grayscale, 1 channel
F - 32-bit floats, grayscale, 1 channel
CMYK - 8 bits per channel, 4 channels
YCbCr - 8 bits per channel, 3 channels
```